# How can I update 2 mysql rows at once?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, user a, gives $100 to user b,

would I have to perform seperate queries to update each user's $, or can I do it in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create store procedure which would handle this 2 updates and wrap it up with transaction what would be wise

Comment: Thanks, I will defo look this up in the morning!

Comment: +1 For transactions. The money transfer question is classic text book scenario for transactions

Answer (score 1):

If $100 is going from "a" to "b", do as follows.  This is kind of ugly, but it is possible.  Two sql statements is probably much cleaner.  The next guy inheriting your code is going to want to know why you did this... :)

```
update account
set value = value + if(user='a', -100, 100)
where user in ('a', 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a reasonably new MySQL Version (5.x i think) and that you are not using MyISAM, [Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) is what you need.

Transactions basically group multiple sql statements together and then allows you to commit them all at once. If any of the statements throw an error, the transaction is rolled back.

Transactions either succeed or fail completely, so you can't run into the problem where the deduction succeeds but the crediting fails.

AFAIK, MySQL 4.x and MyISAM do not support transactions, so MySQL 5.x and InnoDB is required, but I'm not sure what's the current default database engine MySQL Uses.